# Use Doctrine without Apcu on Akeneo PIM

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, akeneo

I moved a Akeneo PIM 1.7 installation to a new server.
This Server does not have Apcu and cant because of suPHP. (CWP is used for administration)

As Doctrine supports many cache backends, it should be possible to use it without, right?
But I keep gette this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\apcu_fetch() in /.../vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcuCache.php on line 36
```

I tried to add to the config.yml:

```
doctrine:
  ...
  orm:
    ...
    metadata_cache_driver:  redis
    query_cache_driver:     redis
    result_cache_driver:    redis
```

But doctrine keeps trying to use Apcu.
How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out this isn't a issue with Doctrine. It's Akeneo which calls APCU directly, so changing Doctrine config won't help.

Sadly Akeneo just won't run without it.

So using a PHP handler which allows the use of APCU is the resoluton. We installed it on another Server using PHP-FPM.

If someone using CWP finds this post, you could use DSO: http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/dso-php-handler-for-cwp - But have a look at the drawbacks.